# Can I and how do I use a custom class as a data type?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a small address book application in c#. The form has inputs for name, address, city, state, and zip. Upon saving those need to go into a listbox. The app contains 2 custom classes(address and friend). Looking at the class diagram it looks like the Address class is the data type for location in the Friend class. Can I use the custom class Address as the data type for the friend class? The address class has the fields for address, city, state, zip and the friend class has the field for name. I gather that field location in the Friend class gets its information from all of the fields of the Address class, but I don't know how to get that information to the Friend class and the listbox.  Hopefully this question isn't too muddled. I am not too worried about the photo portion of this one right now.
Friend class:

```
namespace Friends
{
public class Friend
{
    #region [Fields]
    private string _name;
    private Address _location;
    private string _photo;
    #endregion

    #region [Properties]
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Name", "Please enter a name");
            _name = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    public Address Location { get; set }
    public string Photo
    {
        get { return _photo; }
        set { _photo = null;}
    }
    #endregion
    #region Constructors
    public Friend()
    {
        this.Name = String.Empty;
        this.Photo = null;
    }
    public Friend(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Photo = null;
    }
    public Friend(string name, Address location)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Location = location;
        this.Photo = null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return this.Name + " -- " + this.Location;
    }
    #endregion
    }
}
```

Code behind form that doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PersonInfo;


namespace Friends
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Friend> myFriend = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myFriend = new List<Friend>();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Friend f = new Friend()
        {               
            f.Name = txtName.Text,
            f.Location.Street = txtAddress.Text,
            f.Location.City = txtCity.Text,
            f.Location.State = txtState.Text,
            f.Location.Zip5 = txtZip.Text                
        };                            

        lstContacts.Items.Add(f);

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
}
```

If this question needs more clarification or needs to be broken into separate questions, please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us some more information? For example, does your code work at the moment? What is the output? Are you seeing strange results? What do you expect?

Comment: Im sorry, I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: My expectation is for an output similar to "Scott - 123 AnyPlace Park City, UT 12345" into the list box.  I guess it boils down to how do I get the information from my text boxes to pass through the Address class into the Field class and end up in my listbox?  I have never dealt with 2 custom classes in this way.

Comment: What is your current output? Is it: "Scott - Your.Namespace.Address" ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The current output is just "Scott --"  I have a bunch of build errors saying invalid initializer member declarator. And also Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'Friends.Friend' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `ToString` on your `Address` class so that it too can render its own output:

```
public class Address {
    // .. other code here

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Join(",", this.AddressLine, this.City, this.Suburb, this.State, this.Postcode);
    }
}
```

This will result in: `Name - AddressLine, City, Suburb, State, Postcode` (with proper values)

You may also have to call `ToString` in your `Friend` class:

```
public class Friend {
    // ...other code here

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Name + " -- " + this.Location.ToString(); // <-- this
    }
}
```

Also, you need to initialize your `Location` property in your first constructor to avoid `NullReferenceException`s being thrown:

```
public Friend(string name) {
    // .. other stuff here
    this.Location = new Address();
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I totally misunderstood what the OP wanted. You beat me to it, sir. :)

Comment: +1 for asking for clarification before posting answer rather than playing quick-draw.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead  It looks like I am getting closer. I am getting a "invalid initializer member declarator" for the 4 lines that start f.location in my btn_Save click. It is like it isn't reading those text boxes and still coming up with Scott --

Comment: @ScottT Remove the `f.`. You don't need that in the initialization list.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead If I drop the f. I still get the same error and a second one "System.Drawing.Point does not contain a definition for "Street" and no extension method "Street" accepting a first argument of type "system.drawing.point" could be found(are you missin a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Is your `Location` property a `Point` type or `Address` type? In your example in your question it is an `Address`. Your error seems to assume its a `Point` though...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It is definitely an Address type.

Comment: Then I would suggest both a full Clean and Rebuild of your project.. and to update your question with relevant code and the line that has the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear and easy to understand. I think what you want to do is to be able to get a user's friend's address info in a relational way.

I'll try to explain it but if I didn't understand your question correct, please clarify what do you want to know exactly.

Note: I'm using auto-properties to keep code samples short.

Here is your person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressInfo Address { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        //Avoid object reference not set exception.
        Friends = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

And the AddressInfo class to model an address.

```
public class AddressInfo
{
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    //More fields can be added if necessary.
}
```

To instantiate a person with an address:

```
Person newRecord = new Person();
newRecord.Name = "John Smith";
newRecord.Address = new AddressInfo();
newRecord.Address.ZipCode = 1234;
newRecord.Address.Address = "Sesame street.";
```

And if you want to associate two persons as friends you simply add that person to other's Friends collection.

```
Person myFriend = new Person();
myFriend.Name = "John Doe";
myFriend.Address = new AddressInfo { ZipCode = 1234, Address = "Some street..." };

newRecord.Friends.Add(myFriend);
```

I hope you get the relations between objects in here. When you need to get a person's friends you simply iterate through the "Friends" collection of said person object.

If you use Linq, you can also query the Friends collection. E.g: myPerson.Friends.Where(f => f.Name == "John Doe").FirstOrDefault();

As for the persistance, if you're using a database (like SQL Server) you probably would like to use Entity Framework as your ORM (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or, for a desktop application like address book I'd suggest you to use XML files to make contact lists easily portable between devices.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use like that:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


    public class Friend: IValidatableObject

    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public Address Location { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
         return  string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", this.Location.Line1, this.Location.City, this.Location.State, this.Location.Zip);
       }
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                foreach (var validationResult in results)
                {
                    results.Add(validationResult);
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
    }





public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Neet and simple.

For validation you can call Validate Method Or use Modelstate.isvalid.

Comment: You have made the assumption that this is based on MVC. It is not. Also, you appear to be talking about validation.. which I don't see anywhere in the question.

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` ? ... Validation doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question...

Comment: Did my code ever used that ? I have just given an option because I don't know if he is using...

Comment: You have done your bid by marking it down. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: If you can convince me your answer has _some remote relation_ to the OP's question I will happily remove my downvote. For now though.. your answer does not appear to share any context with the question.

Comment: If validation is not in the question then what it is -   if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Name", "Please enter a name");
            _name = value.Trim();
        } HOw did you got 28K ??

Comment: Did you read the question or just look at the code? Where has the OP said "I need help with validation"?